# Generate random doubles out of the whole positive range of doubles

Tags: java, random, double

for testing a specific math function I implemented I need to generate a lot of doubles in the full range of doubles > 0. So the random generated value should be between 2^−52 × 2^−1022 and (2−(2^−52)) × 2^1023. I tried using

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(origin, bound)
```

but it only gives values close to 1e300.

I tested it with

```
    public void testRandomDouble() {
        double current;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
                current = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

                if (current < min) {
                    min = current;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(min);
        }
    }
```

generating the output

```
1.2100736287390257E300
1.2292284466505449E300
1.4318629398915128E299
6.922983256724938E299
1.3927453080775622E300
4.8454315085367987E300
1.4899199386555683E299
3.7592835763389994E299
2.0561053862668256E300
1.6268118313101214E299
```

Even when recompiling and rerunning the test (so the local thread has a different seed) results in approx. the same output. I didn't find anything about this behavior online. What am I missing?

Comment: For the number range you specified (2^-52 * 2^-1022) you're likely going to run into the limits of what `double` can represent. Have you tried with something like `BigDecimal`?

Comment: the number range I specified is the range of a double according to [IEEE 754](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) but I am not using those exact values anyways. I am using Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE in my code.
I cannot use BigDecimal because of the way my program works.

Comment: I see the issue now, and it's definitely strange. Reading the source code at the moment.

Comment: So `ThreadLocalRandom#nextDouble(origin, bound)` does a correction via `r = r * (bound - origin) + origin;`. I suspect this is the primary cause of the issue, since `Double.MAX_VALUE - Double.MIN_VALUE` would "overflow" the `Double.MAX_VALUE` (since `MIN_VALUE` is negative). If you check the value of `Double.MAX_VALUE - Double.MIN_VALUE`, you'll end up with `1.7976931348623157E308`, which is in-line with your results. If you're looking to generate _any_ double, I would stick with just `#nextDouble()` which should be in the range you specify anyhow.

Comment: @user16320675 you're right, `MIN_VALUE` is the smallest non-zero value (my mistake there). **However**: `bound - origin` will mean `origin` (the largest double) is now a negative operand. There's still a little more investigation to be done here, but that should get someone reasonably close to the answer.

Comment: I did the test in my JUnit test class, so the 10 numbers are generated because of the annotation @RepeatedTest(10) and restarting the test I meant recompile and rerun
Edit: I edited my test code so it is more clear now

Comment: If I use nextDouble() (without parameters) i get the same problem but around e-9 instead of e300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ten times as many values in the range 1e300 as 1e299, and ten times as many values in the range 1e299 as in 298.  This shouldn't necessarily be surprising!  You should *expect* 90% of your values to be e300, 99% to be e299 or e300, etc.  If you want a uniform distribution over *the values that can possibly be held in a double*, not a uniform distribution over the number line, you will need a very different algorithm.  That would probably look something like

```
double d;
do {
  d = Double.longBitsToDouble(random.nextLong());
} while (Double.isNaN(d) || Double.isInfinite(d) ||  d <= 0);
return d;
```

Comment: Your answer will probably work, but there arent 10 times more number between 1e300 and 1e299 because of double precision limitations, as it stands there are more or less the same count of numbers (with respect to 2^n, so 2^1023 hast the same amount of numbers as  2^1000)

Comment: There are ten times as many numbers on the _real number line,_ which is the distribution used by `nextDouble`.  (Yes, yes, the infinities are equal and isomorphic, but there's ten times as much probability weight in the uniform distribution.) I have described how to get a uniform distribution over the set of representable double values, if that is what you want instead.

Comment: ahh thats whats causing the troubles, thank you, didn't know nextDouble was generating along a distribution

Comment: Just as an afterthought: there is probably no easy way to modify this algorithm to work withing a range, is there? so i would have to random generate an exponent in the needed range and a double between 0 and 1, or is there a library for random values with a uniform distribution over possible double values ?

Comment: You could probably do it by generating a random `long` in a range between `Double.doubleToLongBits(low)` and `Double.doubleToLongBits(high)`, though you might need some extra work for negative values.